# How exactly is orientation determined for hair particles rendered as objects?

Tags: particles, hair

I am using a Blender 2.8.x hair particle system to render particles using objects, but I cannot figure out precisely how the generated objects are oriented. At least not in all cases. If I do *NOT* check the "Object Rotation" box in the "Render" area of the particle system settings, then empirically it seems to align the local "Y" axis of the model object with whichever axis I choose under "Orientation Axis" in the "Rotation" area. But if I check "Object Rotation", then Blender always seems to apply a 90 degree rotation of some kind when it creates the particles, and *THEN* apply the rotation transform of the model object as well.

Can someone explain EXACTLY how all the particle system options work that control how particles rendered as objects are oriented and rotated?